# C++ Socket Programming

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm wondering if there's any simple and clean way to create, write to, and receive from network sockets in C++. I know in C you can use sys/sockets among other low-level libraries, but is there anything superior for C++? We're on C++-17 and yet I still can't find much about socket programming. On Python it's easy, but C++ makes it intimidating for me.

Comment: The C++ Standard Library doesn't currently support sockets. You can of course use any C features (if your OS supports them), such as those declared in sys/sockets.

Comment: There is boost::asio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C++ standard library does not currently have any socket or network functionality.  The standards committee does have a networking subgroup, who are working on a Networking TS ([current draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4711.pdf)), but that didn't make it into C++17.

For the time being, there's [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html), which the Networking TS is largely based upon.  That provides a cross-platform networking interface.  Of course, you can also directly use your OS's networking APIs, such as POSIX sockets or WinSock.

Comment: It will be interesting to see what happens with the Networking TS, I personally think that C++ is due for a good socket library, but that's just me. Asio seems inviting and manageable for now.

Comment: [Yowza.](https://github.com/boostorg/wiki/wiki/Getting-Started%3A-Overview)  *Installing Boost: The initial cloning will take at least 45 minutes on a 3.0 mbps Internet connection and will consume roughly 1.5 GB of disk space.* Seems like a lot.

Comment: Turns out there is a [Non-Boost ASIO library...](https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/)

Answer (score 5):

**2022**

Still nothing in the standard library. However, there is a clean thin solution in the form of [kissnet](https://github.com/Ybalrid/kissnet).

It's a thin wrapper (~1500 lines) around respective socket headers in Linux / Windows.

Secure sockets via OpenSSL.

C++ 17 compiler is required, as they're using `std::byte` and other perks.

Why isn't something like this in the standard library? Beats me.

Comment: …because if you look at the details, it is very far from being good enough to be standardized. The `socket` class is huge, making it very costly to move even if you use none of the advanced features. It also doesn't actually hide OS gimmicks. It has a half-baked SSL support that does not allow proper certificate configuration… need I continue?